# How to set change the variable when the RSI goes above 25 in pine script

Tags: pine-script

In my strategy, I save the low the -1 candle when rsi cross above 25 with ta.valuewhen. But after that, I want to make that value to zero when RSI goes above 50 after that and that value should be stored again only when that cross happens again

I have made this much until now

```
indicator("RSI 25", overlay=false, timeframe="" )
rsi_p=input(14,"RSI Period:")
rsi= ta.rsi(close,rsi_p)[1]
last_signal = 0
value_buy=0.0
value_buy == ta.valuewhen(ta.cross(rsi,25),low,1)
if (ta.cross(rsi,50))
    value_buy:=0.0


buy = high[1]<value_buy
plot(value_buy)

//last_signal = 0
long_final  = buy  and (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0)


alertcondition(long_final, title="Buy signal", message="Buy")
last_signal := long_final ? 1 : 0

plotshape(buy, style=shape.triangleup,
          location=location.belowbar, color=#00ffa8,size=size.tiny,title="buy label",text="Buy",textcolor=#00ffa8)
```

Comment: So, what is your question or problem? How does it work now?

Comment: rsi_p=input(14,"RSI Period:")
rsi= ta.rsi(close,rsi_p)[1]
var float value_buy = na
if (ta.crossover(rsi,25))
    value_buy := low[1]
if (ta.cross(rsi,50))
    value_buy:=na


buy = high[0]<value_buy and high[1]>value_buy


Solved this by this